# Can't SSH via router port-forward when openvpn client running

Tags: networking, router, ssh, openvpn

I have a debian PC on my home network.  I use a dynamic DNS service so I can SSH to the PC from elsewhere on the internet.  I also use port-forwarding on the router, so I map from (say) 2222 at the dynamic address to 22 on the PC.

This all works fine, until I run an openvpn client on the PC.  Then I cannot make the SSH connection.

However, I *can* make an SSH connection from any other PC on the home network direct to the debian PC.  It's just the router's port forward that doesn't work.

Why does the PC see the connection coming from the router to port 22 differently to how it sees a direct connection attempt to port 22?  And why doesn't the connection work?  Ideas welcome!

Answer (score 2):

## Routes

Most VPN software is smart enough to set up routes that ignore Local Area Network (LAN) traffic, so that's why SSH works from your other PCs on your home network.

However, all Internet-destined traffic is still routed out via the VPN interface by default.  This includes connections via port forwarding.  So the SSH traffic enters through your router, but then gets answered through the VPN (which messes it up, since the VPN server has a different IP address.)

One way to solve this would be to set up some iptables firewall rules on your debian PC to send SSH traffic out the normal network interface, and not through the VPN interface.

---

### Example

I've tried adapting [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21118/172556) to this situation (assuming your home router is 192.168.0.1, and your debian PC is 192.168.0.20):

> Edit `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` and add a new table by appending the
>   following line:
>
> ```
> 200 eth-route
> ```
>
> You then need to configure your new routing table named `eth-route`
>   with a default gateway and create rules to conditionally send traffic
>   to that table.
>
> ```
> # Populate secondary routing table
> ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 table eth-route
> # Anything with this fwmark will use the secondary routing table
> ip rule add fwmark 0x1 table eth-route
> # Mark these packets so that iproute can route it through eth-route
> iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -o tun0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 1
> # now rewrite the src-addr
> iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j SNAT --to 192.168.0.20
> ```

Making this automatic would involve either adding these commands to the end of `/etc/rc.local` or making `openvpn` do this stuff when it starts up.

Cross your fingers...

Comment: Could you give an example iptables command that would route ALL ssh traffic via eth0 instead of tun0?  That would certainly be good enough for my use case, if a little broad-brush.